# Unbranded TV card not working

Tags: tv-tuner

I bought an unbranded tv card and I cannot seem to get it to work. At some point I wanted to quit Ubuntu and go back to windows for this. Someone please help me, I been coping with Ubuntu for months now with no major problems I could not fix.

Comment: Is it a PCI video card or USB? If it is PCI, please run the terminal command: `lspci -nnk` Pick out the TV card details and post the result as an edit to your question. If it is USB, do likewise with the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1f71:3301

Comment: The built-in driver *usbtv* covers your device. Is it loaded? `lsmod | greo usbtv` Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep usbtv` What have you done to try to get it to work?